Can't sync Visual Studio Code to any account on Ubuntu
I am new to Ubuntu or any Linux distros, so i don't really know what i am doing. But i have searched it for hours, and i have not found anything similar to this case.
This is a fresh installation of Ubuntu and VsCode, so there's not any extension or configuration on it.
My problem is that i can't get Vscode to sync: when i click on Backup and Sync(1st image), and then Sign in(2nd image), a prompt appears telling me to select an account, but i can't do anything, it's frozen(3rd image). Then vscode stops responding(4th image).
First, i installed vscode via snap-store, but as i could not sync to my github account. Then i uninstalled it and tried downloading vscode on the official site and then installing the .deb with dpkg.
The problem continued just like when installed with snap-store.

Did you solve it? Got same issue (ryzen 7 here)

@Dr.G. I didn’t figure it out. So I just reinstalled Ubuntu and for some reason it worked.

I faced the same issue. I just reboot Ubuntu, then it works.
